# How can I limit the memory used by dask when using local processes

Tags: python, matplotlib, dask

I've been trying to plot many figures using `matplotlib`+`dask` through the package [xmovie](https://github.com/jbusecke/xmovie). Xmovie plots each frame as a png in parallel and then joins everything using `ffmpeg`. So this is an embarrassingly parallel task.

My problem is that I'm using a public server ([NCAR CISL's Cheyenne nodes](https://www2.cisl.ucar.edu/resources/computational-systems/cheyenne)), and if I use more than a certain amount of memory they kick me out.

Basically I have 18 available cores to use, and the memory limit kinda varies based on the amount of people using the server. So I generally try to stay below 20GB when running anything on the login nodes and 45GB when running in the computing nodes.

Sometimes these limitations are not a problem (if the data is small), but sometimes it really is. Reading up a bit, I found out that I can limit the memory successfully doing

```py
parallel_plotting.compute(num_workers=18, memory_limit='1GB', processes=False)
```

Running this code I have never been kicked out of the server. However, this code takes a long time for what I'm trying to run. For example, this is the output running things with these flags:

```
(p39) user@cheyenne3:~/work_cheyenne/inst_postproc$ time peak_memusage.exe python -W ignore vid00_xmov2d.py 
Running: python -W ignore vid00_xmov2d.py; sleep 1  - Please wait...
Start frame saving
[########################################] | 100% Completed | 23min 32.4s
Movie created at FNN_SIsurfjet4_horvort.mp4
Used memory in task 0: 14233.43MiB (+5.16MiB overhead). ExitStatus: 0. Signal: 0

real    24m18.610s
user    22m50.752s
sys 1m37.062s
```

However, if I run exactly the same code (with the exact same data) but change that line to

```py
parallel_plotting.compute(num_workers=18, memory_limit='1GB', scheduler="processes")
```

Then my code runs around 10 times faster:

```
(p39) user@cheyenne3:~/work_cheyenne/inst_postproc$ time peak_memusage.exe python -W ignore vid00_xmov2d.py 
Running: python -W ignore vid00_xmov2d.py; sleep 1  - Please wait...
Start frame saving
[########################################] | 100% Completed |  1min 59.5s
Movie created at FNN_SIsurfjet4_horvort.mp4
Used memory in task 0: 3049.33MiB (+5.16MiB overhead). ExitStatus: 0. Signal: 0

real    2m33.598s
user    28m44.785s
sys 3m0.522s
```

The problem is that sometimes running the latter code I get kicked out of the server (presumably for using too much memory, even though in this specific case the memory used in the second example was smaller).

I actually have two questions:

- What is the difference between the two times of scheduling? I read Dask's docs of the schedulers but honestly I couldn't understand the difference between these two.
- How can I reliably limit the memory using `scheduler="processes"`?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) is ask at xmovie or xarray or on the xarray Gitter.  2) why are you running this on a login node versus just submitting as a batch job where you can likely get the memory you want?  Most clusters frown on multi core processing jobs on the login nodes.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Sorry, I don't understand the first comment.

Comment: @JodyKlymak As for 2), if I use the computing nodes, the problem persists. Only at a different scale. I'll change the question

Comment: For 1) I meant that I'd ask on the respective project gitter or GitHub pages.  They are relatively small communities

Comment: BTW the dumb parallel way to do what you want is to make a 1000 pngs and then make the movie afterwards with ffmpeg.  Then you never have to hold all the frames in memory anywhere.   But maybe xmovie has a good solution for this - I don't use it

Comment: @JodyKlymak for 1) I actually was gonna ask at Dask's issues page, but they redirected me to SO fr this question. (Really this is a Dask question I think, not xarray.)

Comment: @JodyKlymak About the pngs. That is exactly what xmovie does. Except that it plots the frames in parallel. So in theory there should be no accumulation of memory, which makes this whole thing pretty weird.